# Passing a functor into a templated function

Tags: c++, templates, functor

I am new to templating, but I am trying to make my primms algorithm work with two different distance calculators(thats what the functors are for) based on different constraints for a school project (they calculate the distance differently, one depends on if we care about terrain and the other does not). I declare like this

```
template <typename func>
    double mst_mode(std::vector<primms_vertex> &mst_vec, const func &comp){
```

But later in the function when I attempt to use it like this:

```
if(i != working_vertex && !mst_vec[i].been_visited && mst_vec[i].distance > comp(mst_vec[working_vertex], mst_vec[i])){
```

I get the following errors :

No matching function for call to object of type 'const primms_vertex::euclids_distance'
No matching function for call to object of type 'const primms_vertex::primms_distance'

One example of me calling the function is:

```
poke->mst_mode(poke->primms_vector, primms_vertex::primms_distance());
```

(the project is pokemon themed so excuse the funny class name)
Both of the functors take in the exact same thing, 2 mst_vertex's, which is exactly what I am getting when I index into mst_vec. So I cannot figure out for the life of me what the compiler is complaining about. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with an [mre] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: I can't just copy and paste the code in its entirety, because I would be in danger of being honor boarded. I included everything relevant to the error to my knowledge (how I declare the function, how I use it, and what the error is giving me, and why the error is confusing)

Comment: Sorry but you have not provided enough information.  We need enough code that we can copy and paste it into our own compilers.  Without that we can't give you an answer.

Comment: you are not asked to past he code in its entierty, but you must show an example that lets others reproduce the problem. To quote an ancient saying: We have no magic crystal ball, hence you have to show the code

Comment: Okay, perhaps this is a better one to take to office hours. I thought my mistake would be clear based on how I declared everything, but that shows how little I understand the error I am making I guess. Thank you anyways!

Comment: Now that I've seen what `primms_vertex::primms_distance` is, I notice that it's `operator()` is not marked as `const`.  It needs to be so marked since `cmp` is a const reference.

Comment: I agree with Nathan. Furthermore there are some reasons for passing your Functor per value. If you are concerned because your Functor is expensive to copy, you should probably redesign it, since that is what all stl-algorithms do. Hence, if you want to use one of them at some point with your functor it should be inexpensive to copy.

Comment: `primms_vertex::primms_distance()` seems suspicious but we don't know because we don't see how it is declared. It look like you are calling a function that would return a functor!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
#include <vector>

struct primms_vertex {
    bool been_visited{};
    size_t distance{};
    static size_t primms_distance(primms_vertex const& left, primms_vertex const& right);
};

size_t primms_vertex::primms_distance(primms_vertex const& left, primms_vertex const& right) {
    return left.distance < right.distance;
}

struct Poke {
    std::vector<primms_vertex> primms_vector;

    template <typename func>
    double mst_mode(std::vector<primms_vertex>& mst_vec, const func& comp) {
        size_t working_vertex{ 42 };
        for (size_t i = 0; i < mst_vec.size(); i++) {
            if (i != working_vertex && !mst_vec[i].been_visited && mst_vec[i].distance > comp(mst_vec[working_vertex], mst_vec[i])) {
                // do something.
            }
        }
        return 0.0;
    }

};

int main() {
    Poke* poke{}; // TODO: Instantiate a Poke.
    poke->mst_mode(poke->primms_vector, primms_vertex::primms_distance);
    return 0;
}
```